# iOS push notification server configuration

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This is my php code for push notification. I have generated the .pem file and it works while executing "php push.php" from localhost. I put it to live site and when I execute this script" 101 timeout error occurs. I have put the .pem file and this script in the same folder. What server side setup am I missing? Can you guys plz kindly help me on this?

```
  <?php

    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
    $deviceToken = //Device Token 

    // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = //Passphrase

    // Put your alert message here:
    $message = 'My first push notification!';


    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

Comment: Server side we don't need to configure anything. Check your file permissions.

Comment: are you testing with a DEBUG or PROD build?

Comment: I gave permission to the script file - 777 but it gives this error. -"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." And testing in release build @nburk

Comment: did you recreate the .pem file for the release build? that's a common issue, that when switching from debug to production builds (when in debug everything runs fine) suddenly push is not working for release builds. that's because you have to repeat the whole procedure of creating the .pem file with a prodcution certificate.

Comment: No I am using the same .pem file that I used for testing locally. And I tested it in another server. It's working fine. I think some server setting is not correct.:( And I cant figure out what

Comment: is there any firewall blocking outgoing traffic ?

Comment: I think it's because my server is in shared hosting.